# Creating a Leader-board in Python 3, the leader-board must be sorted from highest to lowest

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, database, dictionary, text-files

I need to create a leader board in python 3, the data of the leader board is in an external '.txt' file. Also, the leader board must be sorted from highest to lowest. Also, can you sort it out in a clean leader-board format - without the square brackets, squiggly brackets and the additional commas. I was thinking of maybe using an array or dictionary, but i'm not really sure how to use it

```py
#this is a relevant snippet of my code

f = open("scores.txt", "r")
content = f.read()
content.sort()
print(content)
```

```
#this is the text file with the names and scores

Muaadh: 5
Yasir: 6
Zaim: 7
Ishfaq: 5
Tanzeel: 87
Hamzah: 3
Muhammed: 5
Muaadh: 6
Yasir: 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have improved @kdq0 code, now it will sort a mixture of double, single and negative digits. I have also shortened the code.This code was written assuming that the text file is named 'Results.txt'

```py
import csv

with open('Results.txt', newline='') as f:
  readData = csv.reader(f, delimiter= ':')
  sortScores = sorted(readData, key=lambda i: int(i[1]), reverse=True)
  for row in sortScores:
    print(row[0] +":" +row[1])
```

Comment: My code also works for everything you say you improved. Also you did not shorten the code. You renamed variables. Please don't get the two confused.

Comment: @kdq0 nope, it didn't work for negative numbers, but when I added int(i[1]) it worked!

Comment: @kdq0 Thank you for your help anyway - it guided me to the final answer anyway

Comment: Are your numbers being stored as quoted strings? Otherwise you shouldn't need to cast them as integers.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, assuming the data you gave is in a file named sort-test.txt, with no header:

```
import csv

with open('sort-test.txt', newline='') as f:
    data = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=':', fieldnames=['name', 'score'], quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)]

sorted_data = sorted(data, key = lambda i: i['score'], reverse=True)
for x in sorted_data:
    print (x['name'] + ': ' + x['score'])
```

Comment: it works, however can you sort it out in a clean leader-board format - without the square brackets, squiggly brackets and the additional commas. please

Comment: Modified to loop through the dict and print rows. Please remove the downvote as the answer was not incorrect, just wasn't laid out all the way.